# The license of auto-generated source-code

Tags: software, licensing

I have a C# application released under BSD 2-clause license. This application takes an XML file (MIT licensed) describing a software interface and generates the said interface as C# code. What license applies to the generated code? BSD 2-clause - as the generating application, or MIT - inherited from the interface description.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bluedog While this **could** be addressed om the opensource stack, this is a specifically legal issue, and is probably better addressed here. It is surely on-topic here. I see no reason to close it.